# C error with linker when attempting include mysql-connector-c

Tags: mysql, c, cmake, mysql-connector

When I am trying to use C mysql-connector from official web-site [Connector/C](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) I got an error which is hard to resolve for a person who is just learning C.

#Here is CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(MYSQL_CONNECTOR C:/mysql-connector-c)
include_directories(${MYSQL_CONNECTOR}/include)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(untitled ${MYSQL_CONNECTOR}/lib/libmysql.lib)
```

#Dummy code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main (void) {
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    char *server = "localhost";
    char *user = "root";
    char *password = "";
    char *database = "core_loc";

    /*****/
    /*some dummy query*/
    return 1
}
```

#Error

[image]

Comment: I am using CLion, compiler mingw from Qt framework

Comment: Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your question to replace them with the respective code. Additionally, questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Without this, your question is off-topic and liable to be closed. Please construct a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen e.g. when you mix architectures between app and libs (32bit <-> 64bit). MinGW bundled with Qt is 32-bit i.e. you have to download 'mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-win32.zip' from dev.mysql.com host.